# Regarding job's failure running in oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Job running in oozie is getting the following error:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~/oozie/distro/target/oozie-3.3.2-distro/oozie-3.3.2$ bin/oozie job -oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
Error: E0902 : E0902: Exception occured: [Call to 127.0.0.1:8020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe]
```

How can I solve this. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on how to ask a good question. Perhaps edit your question and add what you are trying to do, why you think its not working, and anything you have tried to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Oozie has trouble connecting to your name-node.

Its trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:8020, is this where the namenode is running?

If yes, double check it is running.

If no, make sure job.properties has a line like: nameNode=hdfs://namenode_host:8020

Which should point to the correct name node location.

Reference ${nameNode} in the  section of your action.